# How to create custom distance function with multiple arguments for sklearn

Tags: python, function, scikit-learn, arguments, distance

To create a distance function for sklearn, I need a function that takes two one dimensional array as the input and return a distance a the output. I want to try different distance functions from the paper [Similarity Measures for Categorical Data: A Comparative Evaluation](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.140.8831&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Some of the need extra information about the data.

Lets take the hamming distance as an example and assume that x is label encoded data:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

def hamming(a,b):
    return sum(a!=b)/len(a)

x = np.array([[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1],[2, 2, 3],[2, 2, 4]])

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric(metric='pyfunc', func=hamming)
dist.pairwise(x)
```

This works fine, but for some of the distance functions I would need to pass the original data as an argument (for example to calculate the relative frequency of an attribute value).

In the example of the hamming distance this would look like this:

```
def hamming(a,b, x):
    return sum(a!=b)/x.shape[1]
```

I don't know how I could pass such a function (with more arguments) to sklearn.
Even though it's not necessary for the hamming distance, from this example I could derive how to achieve this for further examples.

Comment: There is complicated soln to this problem, but a simple soln is to simply use global variables. Can you provide an example where global variable won't be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it with creating a class for my distances:

```
class distances():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.ncol = x.shape[1]

    def hamming(self, a, b):
        return sum(a != b) / self.ncol

dist = distances(x)

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric(metric='pyfunc', func=dist.hamming)
dist.pairwise(x)
```