# How to create custom distance function with weighted values as vectors

Tags: python, function, scikit-learn, arguments, distance

I want to create a custom distance function with 3 inputs for **SKLEARN**, I managed to find work around solution [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66109650/how-to-create-custom-distance-function-with-multiple-arguments-for-sklearn) which works perfectly. I have a vector of weights for each point in X, and I want to apply the weighting when computing the distance as shown in the image below:

[image]

Here is the code snippet where I tried to implement it:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
import numpy as np
    class distances():
        def __init__(self, w):
            self.w= w

        def weighted_hamming(self, a, b):
            return sum(a != b) * w


    x = np.random.random((4, 3))
    w = np.random.random((4, 1))
    dist = distances(w)

    dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric(metric='pyfunc', func=dist.hamming)
    dist.pairwise(x)
```

How do I implement it such that I don't get this error below:

**TypeError: Custom distance function must accept two vectors and return a float.**

Answer (score 0):

Your `weighted_hamming()` doesn't return a float. It returns a vector of shape `(4,1)` as your `w`.

Comment: Yes I understand, how do I get it to work?

Comment: as far as I understood from your formula you want this: np.dot((a-b)*w, (a-b).T)

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that a, b are vectors of shape (4,3), they are instead (3, ) when I print them in the weighted_hamming() function

Comment: no they are not vectors of shape (4,3). they are only (3,) because the metric calls your function on single rows of x at a time, not all rows of them

Comment: it's like this: for i in range(4): for j in range(4): hamming(x[i], x[j])

Comment: How do I perform a single call on w? I think the call of the `weighted_hamming`  is done somewhere inside the `DistanceMetric` class

Comment: I would suggest to do it manually without using DistanceMetric.get_metric.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246437/discussion-between-leparalamapara-and-bpfrd).

Comment: I have to use the metric functions inside BallTree nearest neighbor model, and if I  manually it won't work inside the sklearn BallTree as stated in the documentation:  
**Additional keywords are passed to the distance metric class**